# Can Cat 5 cable communicate with microcontroller and CPU?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols, tcp

So I was curious if this is possible at all. Currently i have a program running in a micro controller (digi rabbit) that reads SPI data from a chip. I also have TCP/IP protocol set in this program so it sends the SPI data to the server. Microcontroller is programmed in C. Server is in java. I convert SPI data into string and send it over, the server reads the raw data.
But i wanted to know if there is a way that I can read the data from Ethernet port. So what i want is one end of cat 5 cable on micro controller and the other on Ethernet port of the computer. Just for testing purposes that micro controller port and everything is installed properly, before i turn on the server. I am not that experienced with networking. So if anyone can point to a blog, or any tips that would be great. My question is how would i go about it?
Thank You

Comment: I'm not certain I understand you, you want to use the UTP in Cat5 hooked up through a NIC as some kind of signalling mechanism without utilizing the NIC as a network? So, like RS-232 over Ethernet?

Comment: Yeah, essentially like serial communication over Ethernet. Its just to test that everything is working fine, when i am installing it because the server wont be there. Or if there is a better way to test it you can tell me?

Comment: You don't mention the protocol you use between the micro controller and the server (i.e. the protocol on top of TCP, even if it is one you have created yourself) but if it is HTTP based you can find may HTTP/TCP debug tools which will do what you want (e.g. NetTool - http://nettool.sourceforge.net). If this is for some sort of installation check that will be repeatedly carried out for multiple installs you could also just develop a simple version of the server to display the basic comms and even run it on an installers laptop.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is called raw Ethernet. Of course this can be done.

On the microcontroller side you need to follow its Ethernet controller datasheet to send out and receive packets. On the PC side this is a bit more complicated and depends on the OS that is running on the PC. On Windows you can use the WinPcap driver to send and receive raw Ethernet packets.

Be aware, that both Ethernet controllers, the one on the PC and the one on the microcontroller, filter all incoming packets that do not contain the receivers MAC address or any multicast/broadcast address. For a simple check the broadcast address (all address bits are 1) will do.

Also note, that the OS on your PC will transmit all kind of packets as soon as the link is established. So you may use a unique protocol identifier in the type field of your raw Ethernet frame. Check [Wikipedia's article about Ethernet frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame). Btw. don't get confused. You only need to send MAC-adresses, Ethertype and the payload. Everything else, like the CRC, preamble etc., is added by the Ethernet controller automatically.